# Laravel, blank record using create method

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with create() method in Laravel. 
Every time when I try to create new record in database using this code:

```
    $website = Website::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'name' => $request->name,
        'url' => $request->url,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'subcategory_id' => $request->subcategory_id,
        'user_id' => $request->subcategory_extra_id,
    ]);
```

the column user_id (in database) equals to 0 whereas my id is 1. Of course I have fillable variable in my model:

```
    protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'name',
    'url',
    'description',
    'subcategory_id',
];
```

I tried to use constant value instead of auth()->user()->id but I still have 0 as user_id in database. Using save() method solves this problem but I prefer to use create().

Comment: try `dd(auth()->user()->id)`  or `dd(auth()->id())` is it give you correct value?

Answer (score 0):

You have listed `user_id` twice in your keys. The 2nd time, the integer is empty.

```
'user_id' => $request->subcategory_extra_id,
//observe
```

Comment: Didn't noticed that... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why you used `'user_id` two times in your code? 
one is

```
'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
```

and another one is

```
'user_id' => $request->subcategory_extra_id,
```

**Just use one instead of two. And try to use the follwing way:**

```
'user_id' => Auth::user()->id;
```

Remember: in this case you have to `use` the namespace of `Auth` class.

Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

try to use this
  use Auth namespace
and then

```
$website = Website::create([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'name' => $request->name,
        'url' => $request->url,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'subcategory_id' => $request->subcategory_id,
    ]);
```